# maven 3 jar exist but build fails

Tags: maven, maven-3

When i am build my own project i have got error:

```
Failure to find com.google.gwt:gwt-user:jar:2.5 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
```

but physically this jars exist`s in my local repo.
I also have got settings.xml in ~/.m2 but this is settings to my company repos, maybe this is the reason. But i try without this file but fails.

So how i can fix this problem ?

Comment: check that the jar file is in the local cache stored at /m2/repository/com/google/gwt (or so)

Comment: Yes i have got this jar in that location.

Comment: i try fail maybe the problem is that some files was downloaded from my company repos.

Comment: Remove your ~/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/... . See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13374566/651140)

Answer (score 1):

try -U in your command line build